# React.js - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I defined routing with `react-router` and accessed the URL.
Then, the error "Element type is invalid" occurred.

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

`Router` and `Route` is not undefined. 
Do you have any idea to fix it?

index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Users = React.createClass({/*...*/});
var User = React.createClass({/*...*/});

var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="app" handler={App}>
        <Route name="users" path="users" handler={Users}>
            <Route name="user" path="/user/:userId" handler={User} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./public/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/app/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/public/bundle.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/bundle.js');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listen at port 3000');
});
```

Comment: What version of React Router are you using? The `handler` prop is quite outdated (pre v1). Assuming that you are using a newer version, `handler` should be replaced with `component`.

Comment: Thank you. I modified my code.
But still receiving same error message.

Comment: What is the path that you are trying to navigate to when this happens? One of your components must have a bad return value, but it is difficult to say which without seeing more code.

Comment: Remove '/' in front of the path '/user/:userId'. Should be <Route name="user" path="user/:userId" component={User} />

Comment: Thank you! But still error. (I begin thinking this error is due to app.get() at server.js)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed defining the root route.

replace it

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
     <Route name="app" path="app" handler={App}>
        <Route name="users" path="users" handler={Users}>
            <Route name="user" path="/user/:userId" handler={User} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>
```